# How can I describe the status which indicates that it's not the time to start the scheduled task

Tags: expressions, time

Suppose there is a task scheduled to be started at 15:00, and now it's 14:50. How can I describe this status which indicates that it's not the time to start the scheduled task, and still need to await 10 more minutes to start? 
I'm looking for a word , a phrase or someway the natives speakers would say.

Comment: Are you looking for a word, phrase or sentence? Try writing something along the lines of what you want, using *???* in place of the missing term.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

[***To go***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/to_go) is a broadly used idiom when there is some time remaining to wait/finish as it means:

> (idiomatic) ***Remaining. To finish.*** 'In my country, we go to
>   public school for 12 years, and I have three more years to go.'

[Wiktionary]

You can simply say, "10 minutes to go before it starts".

Answer (score 0):

You could go with something along the lines of *[it's.there's] still 10 minutes before the scheduled time*.

Comment: Can I say it's not time yet?

Answer (score 0):

The task is [**pending**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pending):

> about to ​happen or ​waiting to ​happen: *There were ​whispers that a ​deal was pending. The pending ​releases of the ​prisoners are ​meant to ​create a ​climate for ​negotiation.* ( -- Cambridge Dictionaries Online )

Comment: Your example doesn't fit in the context where there is 10 minutes to go before the task starts. It sounds more like, "They have not decided to go ahead with the task yet and it is pending."